# Can anyone tell me the difference between these two image sets in my main div?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
#main #home_banner {
position: relative;
}

#main ul li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
width: 950px;
background-color: red;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container #main {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 950px;
background-color: blue;
border-bottom: #adde64 solid 1px;
}
```

they both have relative positioning and aren't positioned anywhere except the default, and they're both inside main(except the list is created -after- the image in the html).

However the list doesn't appear all the way to the left, instead it appears outwards quite a bit

Comment: Could you put up a fiddle with relevant code?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by some code for the blue container.

Answer (score 1):

Theres two things that I can think of the first is ul's have padding by default so

```
ul
{
padding:0px;
}
```

The second is that display:inline-block adds a small white-space between objects so to get raid of that:

```
ul
{
font-size:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Oh that's perfect.. I didn't know that about ul's. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

IF you want the list all the way to the left, look into padding-start attributes. I think this is what you are asking.

Try setting your lists with the following css:

```
-moz-padding-start: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
-o-padding-start: 0px;
padding-start: 0px;
padding-left:-0px'
```

Comment: This last declaration (where the unit 'px' isn't needed) makes the first 5 ones useless. And I don't even know why you aren't using `padding-left: 0` if this your intent (RTL languages? Are your sites in RTL?). Or if you tested `-ms-`, `-khtml-` and `-o-` in the browsers they're intended for (without padding-start and padding of course): does this even work somewhere?

Comment: Im sorry, im not sure what your question is?

Comment: Only the last declaration is useful and does 100% of the job (except with Right To Left sites). You can remove the others without consequences. After your edit, RTL sites will have their `padding-end` (`-left` for them) set to 0 and also their `padding-start` while LTR sites will have their `padding-start` set to 0 twice or thrice. I don't think this is an expected behaviour

Comment: What is a Right-To-Left site?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture you posted, I'm assuming you're referring to the indented images at the bottom. If you aren't using CSS resets you'll need to set the margins for the ul and li elements. You may also need to adjust the padding of the div that the ul is in.

Answer (score 0):

By default, any `ul` has a `margin` and a `padding` value. Set the `ul` to `{margin:0; padding:0;}` and it will be top left aligned